# Notification texts are not localized in Android P

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am developing an app with English and Arabic language. I have tested in 5.0.2 and 5.1 with Arabic mode. Everything works fine and Notification texts are also localized.

But in Android 9 Pie (API 28), Notification texts are appearing only in English language. **It's not localized to Arabic,** while the whole app localized to Arabic except the Notification texts.

Note: Am triggering the notification from **Foreground Service.**

Comment: Resolved the issue bhai?

Comment: yes, fixed it 3 days ago. I didn't get time to update my answer. I will update it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was updating new Configuration in onCreate() in MainActivity

Now I have updated new Configuration **in Foreground Service too** and this fixed the issue.

Please add `setLanguage();` method in onBind, onRebind and onUnbind in Foreground Service.

```
private void setLanguage() {
    String language = SharedPreferencesUtils.getAppLanguage(this);

    if (language.equals("en")) {
        Swithch_to_English();
    } else {
        Swithch_to_Arabic();
    }
}

private void Swithch_to_English() {
    Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    String current_language = current.toString();

    if (!current_language.equals("en")) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        String languageToLoad = "en";
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        onConfigurationChanged(config);

    }
}

private void Swithch_to_Arabic() {
    Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    String current_language = current.toString();

    if (!current_language.equals("ar")) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        String languageToLoad = "ar";
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        onConfigurationChanged(config);

    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}
```

SharedPreferencesUtils

```
public static String getAppLanguage(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context
            .getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.APP_DATA),
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return settings.getString(context.getString(R.string.selected_language), "en");

}
```